# SQL Case statement with reference to different column in same row

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a select statement that identifies if a customer has signed up multiple times in the past 3 months while still providing all the data in the table I'm working from (example below)

I'm imaging the case query should look something like this but am do not know how to reference the row I want the result to populate in:

```
case when name in
(select name
from table1
where count(name from this row) > 1
and count(email from this row) > 1
and (date from this row) >= getdate()-120
end
```

table has 3 colums:

```
name, email, date
```

Any help?Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you database is `SQL Server 2005` or above then you can write a query as:

```
create table table1 (name varchar(20), email varchar(50), date datetime);
insert into table1 values ('Name1','email@abc.com',getdate()-30);
insert into table1 values ('Name1','email@abc.com',getdate()-60);
insert into table1 values ('Name1','email@abc.com',getdate());
insert into table1 values ('Name2','email2@abc.com',getdate()-20);
insert into table1 values ('Name3','email3@abc.com',getdate());
insert into table1 values ('Name4','email4@abc.com',getdate()-120);

with CTE as
(
select  
row_number() over (partition by [name],[email] order by [name] asc) as rownum,
[name],
[email],
[date]
from table1
where [date] > = GETDATE() - 120
)   
select * from CTE    
where rownum > = 3
```